# How to create a GS1-128 barcode using ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing, gs1-128

Please help with the following situation:

Using ZPL script, I have to generate a barcode with GS1-128 (formally known as Code 128). I have the following specs:

The ideal way to label products is with complex barcodes with delimiters (cf. the GS1 standard, on the GS1-128 barcode model).
The following information is contained in the same barcode:

```
2. SSCC (only for pallet label);
3. EAN code;
4. Quantity;
5. Expiration date;
6. Lot.
```

```
LABEL STRUCTURE EAN 128
(00) - 18 numeric characters
       Example: 712300000000125672 - SSCC - Unique pallet code;
(01) / (02) - 14 numeric characters
              Example: 02911225000004 - EAN article (includes control key);
(3100) - 6 numeric characters, weight in kilograms without decimals
         Example: (3100)000700 represents 700 KG.
(3101) - 6 numeric characters, weight in kilograms with a decimal
         Example: (3101)000700 represents 70.0 KG.
(3102) - 6 numeric characters, weight in kilograms to two decimal places
         Example: (3102)000700 represents 7.00 KG.
(3103) – 6 numeric characters, weight in kilograms to three decimal
         Example: (3103)000700 represents 0.700 KG.
(37) - numeric characters, variable length up to 8 characters - number of packages / pallet.
(17) - 6 numeric characters
       Example: 210730 - Expiry date in AALLZZ format
(10) - alphanumeric characters, variable length up to 20 characters
       Example: 3245AB / 60 - Lot.CODE.
```

In order for the system to read the information in the barcode correctly, it can be created in two ways:

1. The first way is by placing all fields with variable length at the end of the barcode (`(37)` and `(10)`) without the need to insert a GS128 separator in the label.
   EXAMPLE:
   PALLET CODE (SSCC) must always be created separately on the pallet label.
   SSCC code:

   [image: SSCC Code]
   [image: Part 2 of bar code]

   How it looks scanned:

   [image: Scanned code]
2. A second way to create these labels is by inserting the GS128 separator after completing the variable length fields (`(37)` `(10)`) when they are inside the barcode.
   PALLET CODE (SSCC) must always be created separately on the pallet label.
   Example of pallet label with GS128 separator.

   [image: SSCC code]

   It looks scanned like this:

   [image]

   Last part of code:

   [image]

   Looks scanned like:

   [image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: That is a description, but what is your actual question?

Comment: Hi GSerg, the question is how to generate the ZPL script with the request information? Thank you!

Comment: You have pieces of text, and you list them all together in the `^BC` command specifying mode `D`? Page 92 of the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf).